# Set Woocommerce cart item price to zero if the product has already been bought

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

I am unable to override price on second time purchase.

The use case would be: If a user has already bought product "944" then the price would be 0 for next time orders.

Meaning, the customer would pay only for first order of that specific product and it would be free for next orders.

Here my code:

```
 // Enter the ID of the product that shouldn't be purchased again
    $no_repeats_id = 944;
    $no_repeats_product = wc_get_product( $no_repeats_id );

    // Get the current product to check if purchasing should be disabled
    global $product;

    if ( $no_repeats_product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        // Bail if we're not looking at the product page for the non-purchasable product
        if ( ! $no_repeats_product->parent->id === $product->id ) {
            return;
        }

        // Render the purchase restricted message if we are
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $no_repeats_id ) ) {
            sv_render_variation_non_purchasable_message( $product, $no_repeats_id );
        }

    } elseif ( $no_repeats_id === $product->id ) {
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $no_repeats_id ) ) {
            // Create your message for the customer here
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    $target_product_id = 944;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $value ) {
        if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
        /*
        // If your target product is a variation
        if ( $value['variation_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
        */
    }
}

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'sv_purchase_disabled_message', 31 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to make it work in woocommerce 3+ too:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_change_cart_items_price', 10, 1 );
function conditionally_change_cart_items_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Set Here your targeted product ID
    $targeted_product_id = 944;

    // Set Here your custom price (1st purshase)
    $custom_price = 10; // First purshase for product ID 944

    // Detecting if customer has already bought The targeted product (944)
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $customer      = wp_get_current_user();
        $customer_id   = $customer->ID; // customer ID
        $customer_email = $customer->email; // customer email

        if( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $customer_id, $targeted_product_id) )
            $custom_price = 0; // Set to 0 for other purchases (product ID 944)
    }

    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // When targeted product is in cart we change the price
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $targeted_product_id ) {
            // Woocommerce 3+ compatibility
            if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) )
                $cart_item['data']->price = $custom_price;
            else
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $custom_price );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works even in WooCommerce 3+

Comment: It wasn't working. if(! wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $customer_id, $targeted_product_id) ) needs to be if( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $customer_id, $targeted_product_id) )

without !

Comment: @MujtabaK **Updated** sorry I forgot to remove the `!` added when I was making testings, but this code works…

Comment: If I select 5 products from the specific category, there is a $100 charge for all products in cart. I want to limit it to $100 instead of $500 for the first order then $0.00 on next orders.

Comment: @MujtabaK wc_customer_bought_product() function doesn't work with product categories, only with product ID