# Conditionally set cart item prices for specific products in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

In WooCommerce I am using some code from this answer:
[Set WooCommerce cart item price to zero if the product has already been bought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099851/set-woocommerce-cart-item-price-to-zero-if-the-product-has-already-been-bought/46107372#46107372)

It works great with one product, but I would like to make it work **with several products**.

So the code below, for a specific product, change the cart item price to `$0.00` if customer has already purchased and if not the price is set to `$100` *(for the first purchase)*:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_change_cart_items_price', 10, 1 );
function conditionally_change_cart_items_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;


    $targeted_product_id = 1107;

    // Set Here your custom price (1st purshase)
    $custom_price = 100; // First purshase for product ID 1092

    // Detecting if customer has already bought The targeted product (1092)
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $customer      = wp_get_current_user();
        $customer_id   = $customer->ID; // customer ID
        $customer_email = $customer->email; // customer email

        if( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $customer_id, $targeted_product_id) )
            $custom_price = 0; // Set to 0 for other purchases (product ID 1092)
    }

    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // When targeted product is in cart we change the price
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $targeted_product_id ) {
            // Woocommerce 3+ compatibility
            if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) )
                $cart_item['data']->price = $custom_price;
            else
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $custom_price );
        }
    }
}
```

How could I make it work for multiple defined products (instead of one actually)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an array with all target product ids and then you should check if a customer bought this product already in the foreach loop:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_change_cart_items_price', 10, 1 );

function conditionally_change_cart_items_price( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // add as many ids as you need
    $targeted_product_ids = array( 1107, 1108, 1109 );

    // Set Here your custom price (1st purshase)
    $custom_price = 100; // First purshase for target product


    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $customer       = wp_get_current_user();
        $customer_id    = $customer->ID; // customer ID
        $customer_email = $customer->email; // customer email

        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // When targeted product is in cart we change the price
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {

                // Detecting if customer has already bought The targeted product
                if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $customer_id, $targeted_product_id ) )
                    // Set to 0 for other purchases
                    $custom_price = 0;

                // Woocommerce 3+ compatibility
                if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) )
                    $cart_item['data']->price = $custom_price;
                else
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price( $custom_price );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on: [Set Woocommerce cart item price to zero if the product has already been bought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099851/set-woocommerce-cart-item-price-to-zero-if-the-product-has-already-been-bought/46107372#46107372)

You will be able to make it work for multiple defined products IDs *(in an array)* this way:

```
// For WooCommerce version 3 and above (only)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_change_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function conditionally_change_cart_items_prices( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Set HERE the Products to check in this array
    $targeted_product_ids = array( 37, 50, 89, 124, 327 );
    $products_bought = array();

    // Set Here your custom price (1st purshase)
    $custom_price1 = 100; // First purshase
    // Set Here your custom price (more purshases than first)
    $custom_price2 = 0; // Next purshases

    // Detecting if customer has already bought our targeted products
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $customer      = wp_get_current_user();
        $customer_id   = $customer->ID; // customer ID
        $customer_email = $customer->email; // customer email

        // Checking each product in the array
        foreach( $targeted_product_ids as $product_id ){
            if( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $customer_id, $product_id) ){
                // We set all (targeted) purchased products in an array
                $products_purchased[] = $product_id;
            }
        }
    }

    // Checking cart items and changing item prices if needed
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // When a targeted products already purchased is in cart we set price 2
        if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $products_purchased ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $custom_price2 );
        } 
        // When a targeted products is in cart and has not been purchased we set price 1
        elseif ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $custom_price1 );
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works in WooCommerce 3+

Comment: If I select 5 products from the specific category, there is a $100 charge for all products in cart. I want to limit it to $100 instead of $500 for the first order then $0.00 on next orders.

Comment: @MujtabaK 1) you didn't ask for a product category, but for an array of products IDs… 2) Is not possible to check for a product category… 3) Your question is not enough clear as you can have many products in différents quantities, so you have to explain all cases prices in some explicit examples.